# Partial match between two python lists, one list exactly present in the other with few additional characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, string-matching

I have two lists.

```
files = ['26ZJ35_v1.4.doc', '2EPWW9_v1.1.pdf', '344D4Q_v1.8.ppt'. '33ADNL_v3.0.pdf']

baseline_documents  = ['26ZJ35', '2EPWW9']
```

I want to find all the matches in list1 which has an exact string match from list 2 and append to a new list.

Output desired:

```
list3 = ['26ZJ35_v1.4.doc', '2EPWW9_v1.1.pdf']
```

Code till now:

```
import csv
import os
import re
metadata = []
with open('D:/meta_demo.csv', 'r') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for i in rows:
        metadata.append(i)
        #print(i)    
baseline_documents = metadata[1:20]
DIR = 'D:/demo_files/'
files = [i for i in os.listdir(r"D:\demo_files")]

list3 = []
for i in files:
    if re.search(r"[^_]*", i) in baseline_documents:
        list3.append(files)

list3 = [i for i in baseline_documents if re.search(r"[^_]*", i) in files]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
files = ['26ZJ35_v1.4.doc', '2EPWW9_v1.1.pdf', '344D4Q_v1.8.ppt', '33ADNL_v3.0.pdf']
baseline_documents  = ['26ZJ35', '2EPWW9']
result = [i for i in files if i.startswith(tuple(baseline_documents))]
print(result)
```

---

If you need regex use `re.match`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

files = ['26ZJ35_v1.4.doc', '2EPWW9_v1.1.pdf', '344D4Q_v1.8.ppt', '33ADNL_v3.0.pdf']
baseline_documents  = ['26ZJ35', '2EPWW9']
pattern = re.compile("|".join(baseline_documents))

result = [i for i in files if pattern.match(i)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['26ZJ35_v1.4.doc', '2EPWW9_v1.1.pdf']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I use the re.search(r"[^_]*" also?